# How to cast from bool to void*?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm trying to build cairomm for gtkmm on windows using mingw. Compilation breaks at a function call which has a parameter which does a reinterpret_cast of a bool to a void*.

```
cairo_font_face_set_user_data(cobj(), &USER_DATA_KEY_DEFAULT_TEXT_TO_GLYPHS, reinterpret_cast<void*>(true), NULL);
```

This is where the code breaks, and reason is "invalid reinterpret_cast from bool to void*". Why is this happening, and how can I modify this line to get it to compile? Need help

Comment: alternatively you could have a static object: "static char c;" and then pass "&c". the function at the other side could compare the user data against the null pointer. since "&c" can never be a null pointer, that would be a totally portable standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see this is user data and you have control over what is done with the value, cast the bool to an int first: `reinterpret_cast<void *> (static_cast<int> (true))`. Doing this makes sense in that the void* parameter takes the place of template functions in this ANSI-C library. All you need is a true/false value. So, there should be no danger in temporarily encoding this as a pointer as long as it is well documented as such. Really, you would be better off with this: `reinterpret_cast<void *> (1)` or `reinterpret_cast<void *> (+true)`.

Comment: reinterpret_cast<void *> (static_cast<int> (true))
Thanks. This did the trick, and I've been looking for explanations about casting, but couldn't find anything nice. Can you point me to a page that explains casts well?

Comment: wanna make it look cute? try reinterpret_cast<void*>(+ true) :P

Comment: @sahas - This Dan Saks article has a pretty good description of the differences between the various styles of casting in C/C++: http://www.ddj.com/article/printableArticle.jhtml?articleID=191900588&dept_url=/cpp/

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it should work, according to the standard.  Section 3.9.1-7 says bool is an integral type, and 5.2.10-5 says a value of integral type can be explicitly converted to a pointer using reinterpret_cast.  It appears that your compiler is not fully standard.

Could you get away with changing the "true" to a 1?  Converting between integers and pointer types is an old and dishonorable tradition in C and hence C++, and it would be surprising to find a compiler that wouldn't do it.

Or, if you really really have to do this, try (void *)true.  Then wash your hands.

Answer (score 3):

The only compiler I have that complains about this is GCC (MinGW with GCC 3.4.5) - and I'm not sure why.  The standard seems to clearly indicate this is permitted:

> 3.9.1 Fundamental types
>
> ...
>
> Types bool, char, wchar_t, and the
>   signed and unsigned integer types are
>   collectively called integral types.
>
> 5.2.10 Reinterpret cast:
>
> ...
>
> A value of integral type or
>   enumeration type can be explicitly
>   converted to a pointer.

That said, [monjardin's workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606728/how-to-cast-from-bool-to-void/606742#606742) of using `reinterpret_cast<void *> (static_cast<int> (true))` or `reinterpret_cast<void *> (1)` are reasonable workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

reinterpret_cast is a [bad idea](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/017.htm). Tell us more about the problem you're trying to solve, and perhaps we'll find a solution without resorting to reinterpret. Why do you want to convert bool to void*?

Comment: I think he is using a library that stores user data as void*. There is nothing he can do. This is actually a very common way of storing tag data in libraries.

Comment: argh,  yea I agree... I still steer clear from  reinterpret_cast when I can

Comment: Passing a pointer to the user data (i.e. a pointer to a bool) would avoid the nonsensical typecast. (However, it would also require keeping track of the user data's lifetime.)

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, it is highly desirable to have the compiler warn or error on code like `reinterpret_cast<void*>(true)`, even though this code is apparently legal C++. For example, it aids in porting to 64-bit platforms.

Casting a 64-bit pointer into an integral type that is smaller than a pointer (such as `int` or `bool`) is often a bug: you're truncating the pointer's value. Furthermore, the C++ specification doesn't seem to guarantee that you can directly cast a pointer into a smaller integral type (emphasis added):

> 5.2.10.4. A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type *large enough to hold it*. The mapping function is implementation-defined.

Likewise, casting a smaller integral type into a 64-bit pointer (as with `reinterpret_cast<void*>(true)`) is often a bug as well: the compiler has to fill in the pointer's upper bits with something; does it zero-fill or sign-extend? Unless you're writing low-level platform-specific code for memory mapped I/O access or DMA, you usually don't want to be doing this at all, unless you're doing something hacky (like stuffing a Boolean into a pointer). But the C++ specification doesn't seem to say much about this case other than that it is implementation-defined (footnote omitted):

> 5.2.10.5. A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer.*
>
> A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type will have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined.

@monjardin suggested `reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<int>(true))`. If the origin of the error was the mismatch between the integral type's size and the pointer size, then this will work on most 32-bit platforms (where both `int` and `void*` are 32 bits) but fail on most 64-bit platforms (where `int` is 32 bits and `void*` is 64 bits). In that case, replacing `int` in this expression with a pointer-sized integer type such as `uintptr_t` or `DWORD_PTR` (on Windows) should work, since conversions between `bool` and pointer-sized integers are allowed, and so are conversions between pointer-sized integers and pointers.

Later versions of GCC have the following [warning suppression options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html), but [not for C++](http://osdir.com/ml/solaris.opensolaris.tools.general/2006-08/msg00014.html):

> -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast (C and Objective-C only)
>   Suppress warnings from casts to pointer type of an integer of a different size.
>
> -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast (C and Objective-C only)
>   Suppress warnings from casts from a pointer to an integer type of a different size.

Answer (score 0):

It fails because the cast makes no sense - you are taking a boolean true/false value, and asking the compilre to interpret this as a pointer, which in blunt terms is a memory location. The two arent even remotely related.

Answer (score 0):

Try a newer version of your compiler. I just tested and this cast works on at least gcc 4.1 and above. I don't know exactly how gcc versions map to mingw versions though.

Comment: Problem is, official mingw uses gcc 3.4.5, and they say its not going to change in the near future